# Is it Possible to Send a POST Server-Sent Event Request with a Request Body Using Gatling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gatling

I'm currently working on a project where I have implemented a POST endpoint to trigger server-sent events (SSE) with a specific request body. This setup is to facilitate a search functionality involving numerous parameters.

While I'm aware that using POST for SSE might not be the standard approach, it seemed like the simplest solution for my application's needs, so I went with it. However, it must be said that POST requests with SSE are apparently no longer so unusual, since ChatGpt also uses exactly such an endpoint.

Now, I'm facing a challenge with Gatling. From my understanding, Gatling supports SSE with GET requests, but I haven't found clear documentation or examples showing how to handle SSE with POST requests, especially ones that require a request body.

Is it possible to use Gatling to send a POST request for server-sent events with a request body? If so, how can I implement this? Are there any specific configurations or workarounds that I need to be aware of to make this work with Gatling?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Gatling SSE documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/sse/

Another gatling user posted the same question
in the gatling community forum without ever receiveing an answer: https://community.gatling.io/t/sse-connect-via-post-request-possible/6543/1

Comment: Answered on Gatling's community forum: https://community.gatling.io/t/llm-inference-completions-endpoint/8342/3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course it's a shame that Gatling doesn't support this at the moment, but I certainly hope to have this functionality in the future ;-)

Comment: Well, both you and ChatGPT are doing things that are not supported in the SSE specification, hence at your own risk. Then, as mentioned in the thread, we're not opposed to this feature. But the best way to have it land is not to wait idly but to contribute or sponsor :)